# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but not when using breakpoints

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

I am getting a crash on my app. It's occurring on dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: message, but... if I set a breakpoint on the NSLog, and step over, it goes through with problem, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS code is 2 and address 0x4:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x4)
```

I've never had something work with breakpoints and EXC_BAD_ACCESS without them, any ideas?

Please note that my appController is fine. (not released anywhere).

```
if (appController.modalViewController) {
    NSLog(@"==== RETAIN COUNT ====> %d", appController.modalViewController.retainCount);

    [appController.modalViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Retain count logs to **1**

This also ONLY happens for iOS 4.2 and my app is running on iPad only

Comment: And what do your NSLog show when it crash? Since the exception actually tells you that you are trying to access something that probably is released.

Comment: Sure sorry, my bad, yes the retain count is 1, so should be fine right ? Well it is... with breakpoints...

Comment: Have you tried turning on Zombie objects?

Comment: Don't use [retainCount](http://whentouseretaincount.com/).

Comment: @OscarHernandez retainCount can be useful for understanding what's going on when debugging. See, eg, the "Allocations" instrument which provides you with retainCount information at each retain/release event.

Comment: You can't dismiss a modalViewController's modalViewController. `[appController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`.

Comment: Retain count is useless: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Comment: Thanks, still causes problem with your suggestion. ALSO PLEASE NOTE: This also ONLY happens for iOS 4.2 and my app is running on iPad only- just found that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retainCount` is useless. Don't call it.

If you have a crash, you have a backtrace.  Please post it.

---

> I've never had something work with breakpoints and EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   without them, any ideas?

Generally indicates a race condition;  your code is dependent on thread A finishing or not finishing something before thread B hits some particular state.   Need the backtrace.

Comment: Please, by backtrace do you mean the debug navigator ? If not please tell me where i need to go to get this.

Comment: A crash report, or the debug navigator, or go to the debugger prompt and type "thread apply all bt" (I think that is the command) and paste the output into your question.  (Or simply 'bt' as the crashing thread's backtrace in and of itself is probably just fine)

Comment: @bbum: Where is the answer? Right now this is more of a comment.

Comment: That is as much of an answer as can be given with the information OP provided.